# Python using % to substitute variables

Tags: python, syntax

```
def donuts(count):
  strout = 'Number of donuts %s'
  if count >= 10:
    %s('many')
  else:
    %s(str(count))
  return strout
```

I got `SyntaxError: invalid syntax.`

Of course you can do

```
def donuts(count):
  if count < 10:
    return 'Number of donuts: ' + str(count)
  else:
    return 'Number of donuts: many'
```

But just want to ues %, how would this work?
Thanks!

Comment: can anybody tell me why this question got down voted? Highly appreciated~

Comment: this question does not show any research effort,, https://www.google.com/search?q=python+percent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

howbout:

```
def donuts(count):
  somedonuts = 'Number of donuts %s'
  if count >= 10:
    somedonuts %= 'many'
  else:
    somedonuts %= str(count)
  return somedonuts
```

1. don't use `str` for variables, that's already a builtin name (which you colided with in your own code!)  Check `dir(__builtins__)` at the python prompt for the full list.
2. use `%=` which formats the string and replaces the variable with the formatted result.

Answer (score 4):

For python 2.6+ or 3.0+ use http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format:

```
mystr = "Number of donuts: {}"
...
mystr = mystr.format(count)
```

Comment: And you can do stuff like mystr = "number of donuts: {0}. Number of coffees: {1}".format(donut_count, coffee_count)

Answer (score 2):

```
def donuts(count):
  format_str = 'Number of donuts %s'
  if count >= 10:
    return format_str % 'many'
  else:
    return format_str % count
```

P.S. Don't name a variable `str` - there's already a built-in Python function called `str`; shadowing it by naming a variable that can lead to madness.

Answer (score 2):

```
def donuts(count):
    if count >= 10:
      resp = 'many'
    else:
      resp = count
    strout = 'Number of donuts %s' %resp
    return strout
```

Answer (score 1):

String interpolation is the modulus of the string and a tuple (although a single value can be used if it is not a tuple).

```
mystr % ('many',)
mystr % (count,)
```

Answer (score 0):

The % is a binary operator. The left operand should be a string and the right operand should be a tuple with the same number of elements as there are format specifiers in the string (a scalar value will work if there is only one format specifier). In your case you can use it like this:

```
def donuts(count):
    return 'Number of donuts %s' % ('many' if count >= 10 else count)
```

Check the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) for more information.